# How to dynamically show data in a pie chart using Reactjs and D3js

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I've been trying to create a pie chart using d3 and reactjs but not sure where to pass the data that I get from the api dynamically to the pie chart. Does pie charts in d3js accept objects as data because that's how I receive the data from the api, i.e, a label and value

my code looks something like this

```
  performAnalysis = async () => {
    const { enteredText } = this.state;

    const body = { snippetdesc: enteredText };
    const stringifiedBody = JSON.stringify(body);

    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json"
      },
      body: stringifiedBody
    };

    const url = "/api/analyse";

    try {
      const response = await fetch(url, options);
      const result = await response.json();
      const {
        ...sentimentAnalysis
      } = result.scores;

      const sentimentAnalysisArray = Object.entries(sentimentAnalysis).reduce(
        (carry, [emotion, value]) => [
          ...carry,
          { emotion, value: parseInt(parseFloat(value) * 100) }
        ],
        []
      );

      this.setState({
        analysis: {
          ...this.state.analysis,
          sentiments: sentimentAnalysisArray
        }
      });
      console.log("the data"+"\n"+JSON.stringify(this.state.analysis.sentiments)); //need to send this sentiments object to the pie-chart


    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
```

the console log above gives an output like:

**[{"emotion":"Neutral","value":52},{"emotion":"Positive","value":27}, 
  {"emotion":"Negative","value":19}]**

I need to show the above "emotion" and "value" in the pie-chart as labels and values. How do I extract this data and send it to the hooks component?

this is how it would look like in the render for sending the data to the PieHooks component:

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <button onClick={performAnalysis}>Analyse</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span className="label">Pie Chart</span>
        <PieHooks
          data={data}
          width={200}
          height={200}
          innerRadius={60}
          outerRadius={100}
        />
      </div>
</div>
)
```

Comment: which npm are you using for pie chart ???

Comment: @PrakashKarena I just did ```npm install d3``` so it must install the latest version of d3 i think

Comment: i found one example.which shows how you can add customised label with your value have a look https://swizec.com/blog/how-to-make-a-piechart-using-react-and-d3/swizec/6785

Comment: my problem is I don't know how to send the data that I got from the api call to the pieHooks component. Even without the label it would be fine. I just want the values. how do I convert the values to an array and send it to the pie component? the above tutorial doesn't show it

Answer (score 0):

No need to use

```
JSON.stringify(this.state.analysis.sentiments)
```

you directly get your json array  from

```
this.state.analysis.sentiments
```

Comment: I want the `this.state.sentiment` object to be converted into an array and send it as a data. how do I do that?

Comment: what are you getting in your this.state.sentiment ??

Comment: ```[{"emotion":"Neutral","value":52},{"emotion":"Positive","value":27}, {"emotion":"Negative","value":19}]```

Comment: I just want to convert these values to convert to array so that I can send it to the component

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-d3-pie-chart-cu7yi here is example

Comment: yeah I was following the same tutorial from here: https://medium.com/stationfive/how-to-create-a-pie-chart-with-d3-js-and-react-hooks-part-1-81bcd7f39b32 but it doesn't solve my problem to convert the object's values into an array

Comment: i can see that you are storing your array in sentimentAnalysisArray.So,you can use it also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206843/discussion-between-prakash-karena-and-henrydoe).

Answer (score 0):

Here how to convert the data you got from the API to array, but you not sure if this is the format you need

**Update**: based on the Medium article the data set should look like this.

```js
let data = [{"emotion":"Neutral","value":52},{"emotion":"Positive","value":27}, {"emotion":"Negative","value":19}];

let newData = data.map(function(elem) {
  return {
    value: elem.value,
    label: elem.emotion,
  } 
});

console.log(newData)
```